# Comparing list values (numbers, order matters) in Python

Tags: python, list

I tried looking for the answer for this everywhere, I'm sure it is really simple, but somehow I can't make it work.

I have two lists, which have exactly the same quantity of values, and I want to know how many of those match exactly value and position. This is the code I have been using:

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

solved = 0

While solved == 0:
   rr = 0
   i = 0

   userinput = input("Enter a 5 digit number):")
   ListB = []

   for u in userinput:
        ListB.append(u)

   While i < 5:
        if ListA[i] == ListB[i]:
            rr = rr + 1
   print(rr)
   solved = 1
```

The output I'm looking for is, for example, if the input is 12763, 2, but it never seems to evaluate the if as true, so it never adds 1 to `rr`.
I tried a for loop and variations of this setup, but I can't see where I am wrong.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: `While` is not a valid construct in python. Did you mean `while`?

Comment: In Python, it's usual to loop directly over the items in collections, rather than getting those items indirectly using indices (like your `i`). This leads to compact, succinct code, eg `sum(int(c) == u for c, u in zip('12763', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListA` contains integers, while `ListB` will contain (single character) strings. Try using `int(ListB[i])` instead.

Moreover, the inner `while` loop is infinite since `i` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you're overcomplicating things. A couple of list comprehensions should do the trick:

```
ListB = [int(x) for x in userinput]
rr = sum([ListA[i] == ListB[i] for i in range(len(ListA))])
```

Comment: This still has the issue of comparing strings with integers.

Comment: @fuglede yup, nice catch! I was experimenting with the interpreter, and copied the wrong line. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems:

1. `While` should be `while`
2. The input you receive from the user is a string, so when you iterate you should convert it `int` because you wants to compare integers.
3. Your `i`variable is never increasing, so you are in an infinite loop.

Try this:

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

solved = 0

while solved == 0:
   rr = 0
   i = 0

   userinput = input("Enter a 5 digit number):")
   ListB = []

   for u in userinput:
        ListB.append(int(u))

   while i < 5:
        if ListA[i] == ListB[i]:
            rr = rr + 1
        i += 1
   print(rr)
   solved = 1
```

Comment: Can't work this, here :   for u in userinput:
        ListB.append(int(u))

Comment: It seems that input() already knows that the input is an integer. I executed this and got 'int object is not interable. I fixed this by applying str() to either input(), e.g.: str(input() or userinput in the for loop, e.g.: for u in str(userinput().

Comment: @JoshuaStokes sorry I supposed there were 5 numbers but is just 1 with 5  digits

Comment: Hi @Teshtek, just realised I still had my interpreter set to Python 2.7. Oops :)

Comment: @JoshuaStokes, you are right if you are working on Python2.X, but `input()` in Python3 returns a string.

Comment: Yeah, just realised that, see above.

Comment: Oh and if you apply a try statement just before userinput and except ValueError at the end of the script, that should allow only integers for input.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a string. You need to covert the individual digits to `int`s before comparing them. You can also use `zip()` to compare corresponding items from two lists:

```
>>> listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> userinput = input("Enter a 5 digit number: ")
Enter a 5 digit number: 12567
>>> listB = [int(x) for x in userinput]
>>> sum(x == y for x, y in zip(listA, listB))
2
```

Answer (score -1):

I think a solution could be this :

First *while not While* also you never increment i into second while and last how you can get copy into list input? You use space or how? How did you know when you have 5 number? I supose they are divided by space so ?

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

solved = 0

while solved == 0:
  rr = 0
  i = 0

  userinput = input("Enter a 5 digit number: ")
  ListB = [int(x) for x in userinput.split(' ') if x.isdigit()]

  while i < 5:
    if ListA[i] == ListB[i]:
      rr += 1
    i += 1
  print(rr)
  solved = 1
```

If intput is `1 2 3 4 5` so output `5`

UPDATE :
 *If input is 5 digits you havent to split the space so look for the other user solutions*

Comment: The user input has no spaces. See the OP's `input` prompt: `Enter a 5 digit number):"`

Comment: Ok perfect!Thank you

Comment: It seems but it isn't!

Comment: @teshtek, you are supposed to provide an answer that is different from the already provided ones.

Comment: The `while` loop never ends if there are differences, because `i` is not incremented in that case.